# Including tabset panel in sidebarPanel of shiny

Tags: r, tabs, panel, sidebar, shiny

I'm using the package shiny to create an app. I would like to include a tabset panel in my sidebarPanel, like tabsetPanel() does it for the mainPanel() in the user interface. Does anyone knows if or how this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mainPanel` or `sidebarPanel` are just a wrappers for a **div** tag, a sort of html container where you can put any other html valid elements.

For example, you can do this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  # Application title
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input
  sidebarPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
      tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
      tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
    )),
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: This is working fine but how does shiny know just to print the plot when the tabPanel "Plot" is chosen and not giving the "Summary" and "Table" as well. I added tabsetPanel(id="tabname",...) and choose a conditionalPanel(...) in the mainPanel(...) but it still gives all outputs at once.